# Setting up Bitcoin Miner in a data center

Tags: asic, antminer

I have been running Antminer S9 in my apartment. It is too noisy, to hot, and it ruins the ambiance of my home. So I did some research and found a data center that can host my miner.

At home I access Antminer through my private IP through my router. However, in the data center I will have to get a public IP. I will have a strong password for the Antminer but I am still worried for having my ASIC publicly exposed to the world (DoS attacks etc).

I talked to a person in the data center, setting up VPN will further erode my profit margins. It is already expensive.

My questions to the community are:

1. Is it dangerous to set up a remote Antminer in a data center with a public IP?
2. What is a typical network set up when I want to host my equipment remotely?

Comment: Which data center did you find? Since no one has helped you, what did you find out about remote access? You know you can just have a PC server on the lan at the data center and remote into the pc using vpn and windows remote desktop (or whatever), right?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. I definitely wouldn't take the chance. Minimum is a possibility of a DoS attack. I'm not familiar with the Antminer firmware and how that's setup, but you could possibly get hacked in your WebUI. Then they could point your miner at their pool.
2. Yes, a firewall with VPN capabilities and a switch are your typical data center networking setups. You don't really need to set it up that way. You could use a simple home router and turn the WiFi off. Then attach your Antminers to the router. If the router has VPN capabilities, then use that. Otherwise you can setup a computer in the data center to with TeamViewer or LogMeIn. Then you can remotely access your devices through that.

Comment: any router you would recommend for this set up. I periodically have problems with almost any router at home that requires a reboot once in a while. For this application I must try to minimize the necessity of human envelopment since the equipment is remote and datacenter tech support costs $$$

Comment: I haven't actually tried this setup yet (hopefully will soon), so I don't know for sure. I do know that I have a Netgear R6220 at home and I love it. Hardly any problems and it has VPN capabilities that I have used a little bit. Might be overkill though since you don't need any of the wireless functionality.